# Personalized font using Android 5 or higher - XML

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am following this [tutorial](https://johnthiriet.com/xamarin-android-custom-font/) to change the fonts of the app in Xamarin.Android, it is just adding the `.ttf` file to the project and then referring to the `TextView / EditText` where you want to use it in the `XML`, like this:

```
android:fontFamily="@font/sourcerfont"
```

The problem I am having is that it only works with virtual devices, and not with physical ones.

I reread the documentation (the tutorial) and found this part that caught my attention, and I get the impression that the error could be there since my physical device has `API 23 - Android 6.0.1`; and the virtual one has `Android 9.0`:

> This feature is also supported on devices till Android 4.1 by using
> Support Library 26 or more.

[image]

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I don't think you can only use custom fonts on Android apps with versions older than 8.

The only way that works for me on all devices is this but it is very tedious with large apps:

```
TextView Lbl = FindViewById <TextView> (Resource.Id.Lbl34);
            tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "quicks.ttf");
            Lbl.SetTypeface (tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I reread the documentation (the tutorial) and found this part that caught my attention, and I get the impression that the error could be there since my physical device has API 23 - Android 6.0.1; and the virtual one has Android 9.0

I download [Karantina](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Karantina) font family, then creating a folder named **font** under the **Resources** folder. Put the font file inside it, **build action** is set to **AndroidResource** , see the following screenshot:

[image]

I use this custom font:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
   android:text="My text content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:fontFamily="@font/karantinaregular" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="karantina Bold" 
    android:fontFamily="@font/karantinabold"/>
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="karantina Light" 
    android:fontFamily="@font/karantinalight"/>
```

I test my code on Android virtual 8.1(API27), Android physical device 8.1(API27) and Android physical device 6.0(API23), it all works, having no problem.

Comment: Thank you. I did all of that and still not showing on my Android 6 device. Just re-checked rn. Any special detail that you did to replicate in that special device? Sure is an Android 6 device?

Comment: @Kenny.Ali No special setting for Android 6 device, can you try to build on another physical device?